# Get Vimeo Upload Progress in AJAX / PHP

Tags: php, ajax, upload, vimeo, put

I'm trying to combine the Vimeo PHP library (http://github.com/vimeo/vimeo-php-lib/blob/master/vimeo.php) with the BlueImp's jQuery File Uploader (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload). My problem is getting a progress event during the upload process, is this possible? here's the temporary page i'm uploading from (video upload is temporarily hard coded)

```
<?php if($_SESSION['ticket']){ 
  //check upload status
}
?>
<button id="btn">Upload to vimeo</button>
<div id="status"></div>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#btn').click(function(){
//alert('clicked');
$('#status').html('working...'); //this will continue in the background, need to set a session variable so the same file isn't uploaded twice. but how to get response? check ticket ID which should also be part of the session variable
$.ajax({
    url: 'vimeo/upload.php',
    data: { file: '13TimberAlley.mov'}
}).done(function(data){
    alert('done');
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    $('#status').html( obj.video_id != undefined ? 'http://vimeo.com/'+obj.video_id:$('#status').html() );
    $('#status').html( obj.error != undefined || obj.message != undefined ? obj.error+' '+obj.message:$('#status').html() )
    clearInterval(status);
});

status = setInterval(checkUpload,1000);

function checkUpload() {
    //alert('check: reload this page to get session vars?');    
}
});
</script>
```

the Vimeo Upload API (https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload) states that I can check the status of an upload either via streaming (https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#streaming-step4) or post (https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#post-step4)

i can see that the vimeo api uses the post method, but my problem is when/where to return the progress to the browser. if i use the method above (setInterval) then I don't know how to get the ticket id and/or the endpoint from the initial ajax call into the checkUpload javascript function. I thought I could do this via session variables in PHP but I can't get the page to reload (to display the session variables set in the remote file) until the upload has completed

i modified 'vimeo.php' around line 413 with the following:

```
//store ticket id to session variable so we can check upload status, or resume progress indicator if page is reloaded (doesn't work if browser is closed)
session_start(); 
$_SESSION['ticket']=$ticket;
$_SESSION['endpoint']=$endpoint;
```

and around line 500 with the following:

```
// Confirmation successful, return video id
if ($complete->stat == 'ok') {
//upload was successful, we do not need to store this variable to check progress anymore
unset($_SESSION['ticket']);
unset($_SESSION['endpoint']);
$_SESSION['last_upload'] = 'http://vimeo.com/'.$complete->ticket->video_id;
return $complete->ticket->video_id;
}
```

any ideas?

Comment: Any progress with your issue? I'm also interested on solve this problem. Thanks! :)